# Unable to tag EBS Volumes using UserData bash script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, user-data

I have been trying to tag EBS Volumes attached to EC2 instances in the CloudFormation UserData section. Here was my first attempt:

**Example 1:**

```bash
AWS_INSTANCE_ID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
ROOT_DISK_ID=`aws ec2 describe-volumes \
  --filter Name=attachment.instance-id,Values="${AWS_INSTANCE_ID}" \
  --query "Volumes[].VolumeId" --region us-east-1 --out text`
aws ec2 create-tags --resources "${ROOT_DISK_ID}" \
  --tags 'Key=VolumeTagName,Value=VolumeTagValue' --region us-east-1
```

This resulted in a `Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [AWS_INSTANCE_ID, ROOT_DISK_ID] in the Resources block of the template` error.

A post I came across mentioned that using the `!` when calling the variable in the Cloudformation UserData script will get around this, so it now looks like this:

**Example 2:**

```bash
AWS_INSTANCE_ID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
ROOT_DISK_ID=`aws ec2 describe-volumes \
  --filter Name=attachment.instance-id,Values="${!AWS_INSTANCE_ID}" \
  --query "Volumes[].VolumeId" --region us-east-1 --out text`
aws ec2 create-tags --resources "${!ROOT_DISK_ID}" \
  --tags 'Key=VolumeTagName,Value=VolumeTagValue' --region us-east-1
```

This gets around that error, yet still, no tags appear on the Volume attached to an instance launched with this template. If I ssh into the instance and run **Example 1**, it works just fine. **Example 2** does not give me any errors to work with.

What am I doing wrong in bash, that is specific to Cloudformation?

Comment: Do you have `!Sub` or `Fn::Sub` in your `UserData`? Try removing it.

Comment: @kichik I have `Fn::Sub:` and I cannot remove it as it is a fairly complex UserData dependent template. Everything else works just fine so I cannot remove that.

Comment: Can you log into the EC2 instance and look at the file /var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt and also execute the script manually from there. And let us know what happens?

Comment: @AlexHarvey The file looks as I expected, except for the missing `!`. Maybe it is escaped or something. Running the file from there seems to apply the tag as expected. What is going on here then?

Comment: Any clues in the cloud-init.log ?

Comment: Hmm, that file does not show any sign of those command at all

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're trying to create your script using cloudformation, and then executing it on the ec2-instance on startup. Using yaml, this is my userdata section:

```
UserData: !Base64
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - "#!/bin/bash -xe \n"
            - "cat << 'EOF' > /home/ec2-user/script.sh \n"
            - "AWS_INSTANCE_ID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`\n"
            - "ROOT_DISK_ID=`aws ec2 describe-volumes "
            - "--filter Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=\"${AWS_INSTANCE_ID}\" "
            - "--query \"Volumes[*].[VolumeId]\" --region eu-west-1 --out text`\n"
            - "aws ec2 create-tags --resources \"${ROOT_DISK_ID}\" "
            - "--tags 'Key=MyAutoTagName,Value=MyAutoTagValue' --region eu-west-1\n"
            - "EOF\n"
            - "chmod +x /home/ec2-user/script.sh\n"
            - "/home/ec2-user/script.sh\n"
```

I changed the region due to the region I'm using.

If I view the contents of my script.sh file I get the below:

```
AWS_INSTANCE_ID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
ROOT_DISK_ID=`aws ec2 describe-volumes --filter Name=attachment.instance-id,Values="${AWS_INSTANCE_ID}" --query "Volumes[*].[VolumeId]" --region eu-west-1 --out text`
aws ec2 create-tags --resources "${ROOT_DISK_ID}" --tags 'Key=MyAutoTagName,Value=MyAutoTagValue' --region eu-west-1
```

The only difference I can see is your "***Volumes[*].[VolumeId]***", I'm not sure what your userdata section looks like, so it may be issues with escaping.
Using my UserData section above the tag was created as soon as the instance was spun up and userdata section ran.